# Adding a Block Into Region

Tags: blocks, theming

Using several different themes, I'm looking to add a generic region to the bottom of each "content" section of my webpage. The code I have so far is. . . . with Social Share being the name of the block.

Comment: Why you removed code, but leave "The code I have so far is" part? Wasn't it some kind of mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of these different themes enabled (and you aren't using something like Panels), then you can simple edit this from the Block administration page (admin/structure/block).

If you want this to be completely removed from configurability, then I would recommend either doing a preprocess function for the content region (or hard-coding, ick, your custom HTML into the region itself).

Answer (score 0):

[Add a Block Region](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/block-region-drupal-theme/)

1. Modify the Bartik theme directly. Of course, this is not the suggested practice. In the Drupal community, we don't modify Drupal's core unless we are applying a patch.
2. Copy the Bartik theme to the /sites/all/themes directory, rename the theme, and modify it to include the region you desire.

There is a third option, which includes turning Bartik into a base theme and then creating a sub-theme, but that conversation is outside the scope of this [tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/block-region-drupal-theme/).

In this [tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/block-region-drupal-theme/), we will make a copy of Bartik and modify it.

OR

[Working with Blocks and Regions in Drupal](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/blocks-and-regions)